# wireguard vpn: can only ssh in one direction

Tags: wireguard

I have a wireguard server on a AWS EC2 instance. It allows multiple wireguard client machines to successfully connect to each other via ssh.

My problem: I cannot ssh from my laptop (at home) to any machine in the wireguard network (at the office).

However, I can

- ssh to my laptop (at home) from any machine in the wireguard network.
- ping any machine in the wireguard network from my laptop (at home)

Very strange: When I'm in the same network as the other machines (behind the same router at the office) everything works as it should.

Looking at the router settings (at the office), I could not find any particular port forwarding related to wireguard, only ssh being enabled.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Could it be that my router is blocking the wireguard traffic?

**Some more info:**

nmap of L looks like this:

```
Nmap scan report for 11.11.2.101
Host is up (0.065s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
```

nmap of two other machines in the network:

```
Machine 1)
Nmap scan report for 11.11.1.1
Host is up (0.065s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2049/tcp open  nfs

Machine 2)
Nmap scan report for 11.11.1.2
Host is up (0.081s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
2049/tcp open  nfs
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

The fact that there are two subnets might also be part of the problem., but then again: It worked when I was in a wifi behind the same router.

Do I have to open a port on my Wifi router in order for wireguard to work in both directions? If yes, could that be a security risk?

More info:
This is the output of ssh -v:

```
ssh myUser@11.11.1.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myUser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 11.11.1.1 [11.11.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 11.11.1.1:22 as 'myUser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Comment: `the fact that there are two subnets` may be an issue, but there's no indication of the subnet mask in your question so there's no actual evidence of two subnets ... the fact that you seem to be using public IP address range for wireguard may be more of an issue

Comment: How / where am I using a public IP address range? If the "two subnets" were the issue. How come it works when I'm changing the Wifi (from my home Wifi to my office Wifi)

Comment: `How / where am I using a public IP address range?` ... erm ... 11.anything is a public IP address range ... isnt' it?

Comment: `11.0.0.0/8 ... Organization:   DoD Network Information Center` sorry, are you Amerkin Department of Defence?

Comment: ok, but why does ssh work in the other direction if 11.x.x.x was a problem? Also: It works when I'm in my office (behind the same router as used by the other machines in the wireguard network)

Comment: Likewise there is no problem when connecting the machines in the office to each other via their 11.x.x.x wireguard IPs

Comment: routing can be interesting I guess - personally, I wouldn't attempt to use *public* IP addresses that had naff all to do with me, you're just asking for weird things to happen (no, not blackhawk helicopter weird)